# Can Emacs be used to browse a cpio archive?

Tags: dired, archive-mode

Can Emacs be used to browse a cpio archive?

I've tried to open a cpio file in Emacs in Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid), but it simply shows me its content as is, not allowing to browse it as a directory of files.

(Actually, I wanted to browse the initrd.img, which is a compressed cpio archive.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, a `cpio-mode` is not yet among the standard set of modes. Cf.:

- [Re: Proposal: cpio-mode](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-04/msg00824.html)

dated as follows:

```
From:   Stefan Monnier
Subject:    Re: Proposal: cpio-mode
Date:   Thu, 16 Apr 2015 16:42:45 -0400
```

Stefan also suggests some code there:

```
PS: For what it's worth, here's my earlier attempt at such a thing.
```